# Designing an automatic background job attached to a struct

Tags: go, asynchronous, goroutine

Is there a way to program an automatic cancellation of a goroutine associated with a struct when the struct is no longer needed?

I implemented a simple cache for string values (potentially duplicates). Values are stored for a short period of time, so every entry has an expiration time and cache requires a background job that would remove expired values every N minutes.

So I came up with this solution:

```golang
type StrCache struct {
    // ... Values storage
    expiration time.Duration
}

func NewStrCache(expiration time.Duration) *StrCache {
    cache := StrCache{}
    cache.expiration = expiration
    go cache.backgroundCleanup()
    return &cache
}

func (s *StrCache) TryAdd(value string) (alreadyAdded bool) {
    // ... Logic of adding a new value 
}

func (s *StrCache) backgroundCleanup() {
    time.Sleep(s.expiration)
    // ... Removing expired values logic
    go s.backgroundCleanup()
}
```

This suites my use case since `StrCache` should live until app exits. But I don't like it's potentially leaky design: if at some point I would need to replace one instance of `StrCache` by another, the first instance is not going to be cleaned up by GC because a reference to it is held by a self-replicating `backgroundCleanup` goroutine.

I also don't want to introduce a separate method that would signal to stop to background goroutine, since it requires additional actions by package user and introduces a chance to make a mistake.

Is there a way to automatically cancel the `backgroundCleanup` when struct is no longer used? Or should I opt out into other design and only spawn cleanup goroutines in `TryAdd` method? I wanted to avoid it because `TryAdd` uses a mutex for all operations on `StrCache` and holding it locked for longer is undesirable.

Comment: Define "when struct is no longer used". Do you mean when a value of that struct falls out of scope?

Comment: *"if at some point I would need to replace one instance of StrCache by another"* -> Exercise time. Come up with one reasonably realistic scenario where this would be necessary. I'll be honest up front, I can't. This reads to me like anticipating problems which will never come to be.

Comment: [1/2] From the cursory look, I'm afraid you're going to overengineer your solution. I would say, if the background sweeping job evicted a value, then that's just fine: provided no variables in the running program contain references to the evicted value, it will be eventually GC'ed the normal way. So your concern must basically be proper synchronization between TryAdd and the background sweeper (they must not race). (Oh, and if some variables still contain references to the evicted value, it's fine, too: you cannot just remove the variable from under the feet of the clients.)

Comment: [2/2] In other words, I'd make this cache work just by providing an extra reference to a variable, which expires if not used during a preconfigured duration. All the other "normal" references will continue to work.

Comment: @jub0bs _Do you mean when a value of that struct falls out of scope?_ Yes. Basic example would be of a worker that has a defined scope of work and uses this cache instance. When work is done, worker is going to be cleaned up by GC, leaving behind an instance of `StrCache` referenced by a `backgroundCleanup`

Comment: @Gimby, this sort of stuff comes up all the time in tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you consider a different approach for the background goroutine.

On a high level, you should use a `context.Context` in your goroutine which respects [context cancellation](https://go.dev/doc/database/cancel-operations).

```
func (s *StrCache) backgroundCleanup(ctx context.Context) {
    for {
        select {
        case <-time.After(s.expiration):
            // ... Removing expired values logic
            break
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        }
    }
}
```

This pattern will loop endlessly, performing the internal cleanup of expired values. The addition of the context value allows you to quit this background goroutine.

> [...] if at some point I would need to replace one instance of StrCache by another [...]

... then I think you should cancel the context of the previous `StrCache`.

> I also don't want to introduce a separate method that would signal to stop to background goroutine, since it requires additional actions by package user and introduces a chance to make a mistake.

Yes, that is an extra thing users of this type must now consider. IMO that is fine since users of any library should respect concurrency related aspects.

There are plenty of std lib types, which are similar, in that they explicitly document that the usage of those types comes with the need to stop things / free resources ([time.Timer](https://pkg.go.dev/time#NewTicker) is an example).

and a cancel function (see [context.WithCancel](https://pkg.go.dev/context#WithCancel)).

Comment: +1 but, instead of `time.After`, I'd use a `time.Timer` in order to explicitly stop that timer (and terminate the goroutine it uses under the hood) as soon as a context cancellation is detected.